# ParaView - Utilizing OpenGL in a server/client setup

Tags: paraview

I have a question about OpenGL support in a ParaView server/client setup.

My goal is to utilize our cluster for rendering so that my local workstation can act as a thin client or user interface.

From my understanding, this is how such a setup usually works:
The first step is to initialize a ParaView server on a cluster node. This is done by submitting a pilot job to the local grid system. The job runs a small ParaView server init script executing pvsever. pvserver returns a ParaView session URL. The user enters the URL in his local ParaView on his local workstation to establish a connection to the ParaView server node.

Let's assume that the server node supports OpenGL and a XServer is up and running.

How is the pilot job supposed to initialize a X display?

(From my understanding, ParaView needs a X display to invoke a X window for creating OpenGL content on the graphics hardware.)

Comment: Have you found an answer to this question yet?

Answer (score 0):

1. Your workstation runs `paraview` on its own X display.
2. Your cluster runs MPI job spawning `pvserver` using X displays (even without monitors) on cluster nodes, while providing communication port.
3. Your workstations `paraview` connects to server vi that port.
4. Your workstations `paraview` opens case and do the interactive work, and pvservers render and process data.

That is basically the principle, but it depends on real situation how the details looks (MPI, interconnect, environment variables for pvservers, OpenGL direct or not, etc.)